# WiX Managed Code Custom Action Localization

Tags: c#, localization, wix, action

I created a managed code custom action handler library using C#. I tried localizing the DLL, but the default behavior of the Wix.CA.targets execution is to NOT include the language resource DLLs (in their subdirectory structure) in the packaging of the unmanaged code wrapper, thus, I cannot make use of the C# localization.

I really don't wish to put these string in as properties in the MSI, and read them in the custom action handler. This seems clunky, and, for deferred custom actions, unwieldly. I would much prefer to include the localization directly in the custom action handler DLL.

Can anyone tell me how to alter the Wix.CA.targets file to include these language resource DLLs in the packaging so that I can localize successfully? Or, is it simpler than that -  for instance, is there some project property or registry entry I can set?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add post-build event to your CA project. That event should make C# DTF using local .NET culture folder and .resources files for translations with MakeSFxCA.exe. More details - [here](https://buildmaestro.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/c-dtf-using-locale-net-culture-folder-and-resources-files-for-translations-with-makesfxca-exe/) and [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/events-and-actions/how-to-manage). An example of commands which I used: "%wix%SDK\MakeSfxCA.exe"

> "$(TargetDir)CustomActionUtilities.CA.dll" "%wix%SDK\x86\sfxca.dll"
>   "$(TargetDir)CustomActionUtilities.dll"
>   "$(TargetDir)Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"
>   "$(TargetDir)CustomAction.config"
>   "ru-RU\CustomActionUtilities.resources.dll=$(TargetDir)ru-RU\CustomActionUtilities.resources.dll"
>   "C:\Users\Vitaly-work\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\ActivationKeys\CryptoLibrary\bin\Release\CryptoLibrary.dll"
>   "C:\Users\Vitaly-work\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\ActivationKeys\packages\BouncyCastle-Ext.1.7.0\lib\net20\BouncyCastle.CryptoExt.dll"

Note that quotation marks are important for correct handling of the commands by VS.